# Eclipse が 'The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its compation shared library' エラーで起動しない

Tags: java, eclipse

インストール後解凍して、開こうとするとこのような表示が出て起動できません。
対処法お願いします。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its compation shared library
```

Comment: まずは実際に行った手順を明確に記述し、そのエラーに対しどのような対応をしたのか、またOS、JavaSDK、Eclipseのバージョン情報やパッケージ情報もあるとより回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での関連質問 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/7070968 / リンク先でも "OS等の詳しい情報が無いとアドバイスしづらい" とコメントが付いています。行った手順を書きだす事で見落としが無いかのチェックがしやすくなると思います。

Comment: https://qiita.com/bigfirtreeman/items/b4f1fe65f23dd67b25f7